# Validate field input using django serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a field **code** in my Django model.
I have to check if the input string has the following properties:

1. Length should be 5 characters
2. 1st & 2nd characters should be alphabets
3. 3rd & 4th characters should be numbers
4. 5th character should be E or N

I have a serializer as shown below which satisfies the first condition.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=5, min_length=5)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I fulfil the remaining conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining conditions can be fulfilled by adding a custom validator and using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=5, min_length=5)

    def validate_code(self, value):
        # check if the code matches the required pattern
        pattern = r'^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{2}[EN]$'
        if not re.match(pattern, value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Code does not match required format')

        return value
```

The name of the function `validate_code` is not mandatory in the serializer. You can name it whatever you like, as long as it starts with the word "validate" and takes in a value argument. The value argument represents the value of the field being validated.

Here is a bit of in-depth info about the regex pattern used above.

*1st & 2nd characters should be alphabets*:
`[A-Za-z]{2}` matches any two alphabetical characters, ensuring that the first and second characters are alphabet

*3rd & 4th characters should be numbers*:
`\d{2}` matches any two numeric characters, ensuring that the third and fourth characters are numbers

*5th character should be E or N*:
`[EN]` matches either E or N, ensuring that the fifth character is either E or N